# Installing X in Arch

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, xorg

This should be a common enough task. I have just installed Archlinux. Next, I installed `openbox`, surprisingly finding that X is not among it's dependencies. So I installed `xorg-server` as per the opening lines in the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg). However,

```
# startx
bash: startx: command not found
```

On my Debian box,

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/startx
xinit: /usr/bin/startx
```

Yet on the Arch box

```
pacman -S xinit
error: target not found: xinit
```

Later the wiki again refers to `/usr/bin/startx` which doesn't exist for me. What am I missing?

Comment: `pacman -Ss xinit` would have searched package names and descriptions for the keyword `xinit`, and would have shown you the `xorg-xinit` package in the results.  Arch is not a Debian-based distribution and package names from one may be very different on the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit).

> Install the `xorg-xinit` package, which provides both `xinit`, `startx`, and
>   a default `xinitrc` configuration file

```
pacman -S xorg-xinit
```

Comment: It still puzzles me why even the `xorg` package group excludes this small and useful package.

Answer (score 2):

In the past, you had to use [pgkfile](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pkgfile) to search for missing files, now you can use pacman:

```
pacman -Fs startx
```

The equivalent of `dpkg -S /path/to/file` is `pacman -Qo /path/to/file`. (`pacman -S pkg` installs a package)

Comment: This functionality is native to pacman now: `pacman -Fs startx`